# papertrail, set the admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, paper-trail-gem

I am using state_machine and papertrail gems on a model (rails 3.2)

I want to track all state changes and who has originated it, papertrail works like a charm.

Now I have a situation where the system, via a rake take, will change the state of an object.

How do I say to the system who is the current_user (I am using devise) from the rake task?

I want to set that user to be the admin user so that papertrail can store whodunnit.

Answer (score 1):

oh boy, I found the answer here

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#finding-out-who-was-responsible-for-a-change